# what is inverse of $y = 5 ^ {\ln x }$

Tags: functions

**Problem**: What is inverse of $y = 5 ^ {\ln x }$

**Solution**:  $$y = 5 ^ {\ln x }$$

$$ \log_5 y =\ln x  $$

$$ e^{\log_5 y}  = x  $$

After that "I don't know , how to get answer $ x=y^ { \frac {1} {\log5 }}  $

Comment: Invert x with y.

Comment: Do not use logs to base $5$. Write $\ln y=(\ln x)(\ln 5)$, solve for $\ln x$, then take the exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\log_{a} x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln a} $$

Comment: I know the above result But how can we  use it in given question

Comment: $$e^{\log_5y}=(e^{\ln y})^\frac{1}{\ln 5}=y^{\frac{1}{\ln 5}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y = 5 ^ {\ln x } = e^{\ln 5 \times \ln x}$$
$$\ln y = \ln 5 \times \ln x$$
$$\ln x = \frac{1}{\ln5}\ln y = \ln y^\frac{1}{\ln5}$$
$$x = y^\frac{1}{\ln5}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y = 5^{\ln x}$$

$$\ln y = \ln x \ln 5$$

$$\ln x = \frac{\ln y}{\ln 5}$$

$$x = e^{\frac{\ln y}{\ln 5}} = y^{\frac{1}{\ln 5}}$$

Hence $\displaystyle f^{-1}(x) = x^{\frac{1}{\ln 5}} $

Note that the answer may also be expressed as $\displaystyle f^{-1}(x) = x^{\log_5 e} $